# Manage displays of Product:image field directly in Product Display?

Tags: commerce, display-suite

I have a "Product Display" node showing a "Product" (powered by the [Drupal Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) module).

I have installed the [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module, and created a new view mode for the "Product Display" content type.

The problem is that this new mode is associated with the default view mode of "Product," and I see no way to change this.

What I need is to create a new mode for "Product" and get the view mode of "Product Display" associated with this new one.

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: You don't say if "Product" is another content type.

Comment: Product is a "product type" of http://drupal.org/project/commerce module at admin/commerce/products/types/product/display

Comment: i haven't used the display suite but understand it's purpose. for sake of moving your project forward, have you attempted to theme your display with a standard template file for node type product?

Comment: upvoting @austin's comment, that's the way I would go.

Comment: It is a known problem, see http://drupal.org/node/733044 and AFAIK there's no proper solution (yet).

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Manage Display tab of your product entity and enable the same "View Mode" you use at "Product Display". Do it in the "Custom display settings" fieldset.

Then set up image style for the Image field. And see changes at the "Product display" page

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution to this...it's undocumented and really tricky. In you Product Display content type, add a display mode with a custom machine name `my_custom_display`. Now go to your Commerce Product, and add a new display mode and name it `node_my_custom_display`. When you prepend the `node_` it matches up to the other other display and will allow you to chang the field setting from the Product Display content type display mode.

**Quick Summary**

Product View Content Type Display Mode name: `my_custom_dispaly`

Commerce Product Display Mode name: `node_my_custom_display`

Answer (score 0):

Since "Product" is implemented as an entity in Drupal, you should be able to do something similar to the example provided here to create a new View Mode for it: http://mearra.com/blogs/juha-niemi/drupal-7-custom-node-view-modes.

Comment: problem is not how to create a View Mode for "Product" but how to get a View Mode created for "Product Display" related to a new View mode created for "Product"

Comment: under your view, you'd set your row style to something like fields. from there, you can theme your view. click on the theme:information link and use one of those templates to theme your output.

Comment: @chefnelone, you musn't `get a View Mode created for "Product Display" related to a new View mode`. Just go to `Manage Display` tab of your product entity and enable the same "View Mode" you use at "Product Dispaly". Do it in `Custom display settings` fieldset. Then set up image style for the Image field. And see changes at the "Product display" page